# Firebase AppCheck replay protection with OnRequest functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I know i can pass the `consumeAppCheckToken` option to an OnCall firebase function like so

```
exports.myApi= onCall({
  enforceAppCheck: true,
  consumeAppCheckToken: true,
}, async (req) => {.....
```

However, how do i use it with OnRequest?
the options (HttpsOptions) for OnRequests (firebase-functions/v2/https) doesn't have an option for consumeAppCheckToken. Only onCall does. Can I actually not use replay protection for my onRequest function? am I missing something

Thank you.

also, I need to use on request because I'm sending formData.

I've scoured the documentation- nothing